# How to hide the Oracle Apex 19.1 region when no data found

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

How to hide the Oracle Apex 19.1 region when not given the input on above region text box. thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "Server side condition" for that region, use e.g. "Function body that returns Boolean" and put

```
return :P1_ABOVE_REGION_TEXT_BOX is not null;
```

in there.

Alternatively, create a "Show" dynamic action on `P1_ABOVE_REGION_TEXT_BOX` which will show that region if item's value isn't null.